# Python: Get value with xmltodict

Tags: python, xmltodict

I have an XML-file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<session id="2934" name="Valves" docVersion="5.0.1">
    <docInfo>
        <field name="Employee" isMandotory="True">Jake Roberts</field>
        <field name="Section" isOpen="True" isMandotory="False">5</field>
        <field name="Location" isOpen="True" isMandotory="False">Munchen</field>
    </docInfo>
</session>
```

Using xmltodict I want to get the Employee in a string. It is probably quite simple but I can't seem to figure it out.

Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import sys
import xmltodict


with open('valves.xml') as fd:
    doc = xmltodict.parse(fd.read())


print "ID          : %s" % doc['session']['@id']
print "Name        : %s" % doc['session']['@name']
print "Doc Version : %s" % doc['session']['@docVersion']


print "Employee    : %s" % doc['session']['docInfo']['field']


sys.exit(0)
```

With this, I do get all fields in a list, but probably with xmltodict every individual field attribute or element is accessible as a key-value.
How can I access the value "Jake Roberts" like I access the value of docVersion for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are getting is a list of fields where every field is represented by a `dict()`. Explore this dict (e.g. in Python interactive shell) to narrow down how to get to the value you want.

```
>>> doc["session"]["docInfo"]["field"][0]
OrderedDict([(u'@name', u'Employee'), (u'@isMandotory', u'True'), ('#text', u'Jake Roberts')])
```

In order to get to the element value add `["#text"]` to the end of the line in the snippet above.

Comment: @JakeRoberts Welcome! - if a StackOverflow answer solves the problem / answers the question, you have an option of [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark (next to the answer). This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. Note: there is no obligation to do this.