# how do I simplify searching for a list item by an index?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, simplify

I have a simple program:

```py
pos = [1,2]
searched = [
    [1,3,4,6],
    [2,6,7,8],
    [0,1,2,8],
    [5,6,9,2]
]
print(searched[pos[0]][pos[1]])
```

```
7
```

Now what I want is some way to get rid off of `searched[pos[0]][pos[1]]` and just type something like `searched[[pos]]`.

Is there a way to this, or do I have to write out this every time

> I have gotten a lot of suggestions, but what I am searching for is a way to do this in one neat line, simplifying everything.
>   That means that things like using a function, converting to a specific dictionary or even enumerate don't work for me, so for anyone looking at this post later:
>   .
>   I suggest using `np.array(variable)` while defining said variable so you can use `variable[pos]`

Comment: No, Python `list` objects don't support that. You can always write a function, though

Comment: There are many options. You can write helper function e.g, `def get_val(matrix, pos):` that returns this position and then call it `get_val(searched, pos)`

Comment: Or use `numpy` as this will support your desired indexing syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert this to a numpy array and get the search your looking for:

```
import numpy as np
pos = [1,2] 
searched = np.array([ 
  [1,3,4,6], 
  [2,6,7,8], 
  [0,1,2,8], 
  [5,6,9,2] 
  ]) 
print(searched[1,2])  
# 7
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this is acceptable to you, but a function will do:

```
def search_for_list_item_by_index(a_list, row, col):
    return a_list[row][col]

print(search_for_list_item_by_index(searched, 1, 2))
```

This prints `7`, as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by converting your array to numpy as suggested by @oppressionslayer. 
One other way to do that is to create a dictionary and use that as follows:

```
pos = [1,2]
searched = [
    [1,3,4,6],
    [2,6,7,8],
    [0,1,2,8],
    [5,6,9,2]
]
m=4 # width of the searched array
n=4 # hight of the searched array

searched = {(i,j):searched[i][j] for j in range(m) for i in range(n)}

print(searched[1,2]) # prints 7
print(searched[tuple(pos)]) # prints 7
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following function:

```
def func(idx, lst):
    for i in idx:
        lst = lst[i]
    return lst

func(pos, searched)
# 7
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the dictionary approach [like HNMN3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59291275/5827215) but what is fun is you can generalize to non rectangular lists by using `enumerate`:

```
searched = {(row,col):item
              for row,elems in enumerate(searched)
                for col,item in enumerate(elems)}
```

or use [`flatten_data` from my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36582214/5827215) which does the same thing  but works for totally arbitrary nesting including dictionaries.  Probably not the direction you want but worth mentioning.

```
data = flatten_data(searched)
pos = [1,2]
print(data[1,2])
print(data[tuple(pos)])
```